# How to get Data to show side-by-side when using a <asp:PlaceHolder>

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

Can you help me with my search page using visual studio 2013 and asp.net.

I have a simple textbox and a button so a user can search a database for a name and what i am trying to do is when the search button is clicked the results show up on the same page side-by-side as if like a table.

When i do a search at the moment it shows up below each other like this..

```
James
30
Male
Programming
```

but i am trying to show it like..

```
James 30 Male Programming
```

can someone please advise me where i am going wrong. Thank you

```
Dim dsResults As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTableReader



    dsResults = SearchResults(sbox1.Text)
    dt = dsResults.CreateDataReader


    Dim tb As New Table
    Dim tr As New TableRow
    Dim tc As New TableCell
    Dim lb As New Label



    If dt.HasRows = True Then
        Do While dt.Read

            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("name").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("age").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("sex").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("department").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("list_group").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("date_added").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)
        Loop
        dt.Close()
        dsResults.Dispose()

        placeResults.Controls.Add(tb)

    Else

        noResultOutput.Text = "No Results Matched Your Search"

    End If
```

Comment: Have you tried utilizing 3 more table cells and adding each additional component to the adjacent cell? So have tcName as new tablecell, tcAge as new table cell, etc... and then add the controls to the specific cells instead of adding them all to the same one?

Comment: Do you mean add them inside or outside the loop?

Comment: Added an example of what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding everything to the same element give yourself more cells to work with and only add the row once for each WHILE loop.

Edited with less verbose method...

```
    Dim colList() As String = {"name", "age", "sex"}

    Do While dt.Read
        Dim tr As New TableRow

        For Each col As String In colList
            Dim tc As New TableCell

            lb.Text = dt.Item(col).ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
        Next

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)
    Loop
```